# Send username and password using JSON to 401 HTTP Authentication

Tags: php, android, json, authentication, http-status-code-401

I have uploaded sqlite file to the server for the Android app to download whenever any change is made to the database. Now, I want to protect this file so that it not available when accessed using the public URL.

The Android app sends username and password using POST method.

I have set a username and password to the directory where the sqlite file is stored.

Now, the question is how do I authenticate the Android app to download the file but avoid anyone else downloading the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would the app dowload the database?? access the db on the server and make it available via api for the app to call.

Comment: Yes, that could have been a method. But my current implantation is to allow the Android app to download sqlite from the server. This file is stored in a folder on the server. Now I'm trying to figure out how can I password protect and authenticate it.

Answer (score 0):

How did you protect the directory on the webserver? If you did it via .htaccess (it's called HTTP AUTHENTICATION) you can add your authentication to any HTTP call you perform, for example

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(YOUR_URL); 
String credentials = USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD;  
String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);  
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
httpclient.execute(request);
```

Comment: Yes, the directory on web server is protected via .htaccess